# Scrapr text in all <a> tags under a span tag using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy to extract data from web. I am trying to extract the text of anchor tags under a span tag as shown below:

```
<span>.....</span>
<span id = "size_selection_list">
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    .
    .
    .
    <a>
</span>
```

I am using the following xpath logic:

```
t = sel.xpath('//div[starts-with(@id,"size_selection_container")]/span[2]')
for x in t.xpath('.//a'):
....
```

The problem is that the span element is reached but the `<a>` tags are not iterated. What is the mistake here? Also the `<a>` has an href which has javascript. Is this the reason for the problem?

Comment: Your logic works with the sample HTML you provided: http://pastebin.com/hxSZ041j . So either you're not sharing your code as it is or the sample HTML is not what you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

If I would you I would use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup4`.

Please note, this code is untested, but it *should* work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(yoururlhere).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser') #You can use LXML or other things, I am using the standard parser for compatibility
span = div.find('div', {'class': 'theclass'}
tags = span.findAll('a', href=True)
for i in tags:
    print(i.getText()) #getText might not be a function, consider removing the extra ()
    print(i['href']) #<-- This is the links, above is the text
```

I hope this works, please let me know

Comment: But I want to crawl using spider. So that is why I would prefer some solution with respect to scrapy.

Comment: May I ask why using scrapy or spider?

Answer (score 0):

this a all i can do, you html code is not complete.

```
import lxml.html
string = '''<span>.....</span>
<span id = "size_selection_list">
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    .
    .
    .
    <a>....</a>
</span>'''

html = lxml.html.fromstring(string)
for a in html.xpath('//span[@id="size_selection_list"]//a'):
    print(a.tag)
```

out:

```
a
a
a
```